# Python Conversion of Generic list to List[str] (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, casting

I am facing an issue with my code. Where I need to extract a list of strings from dictionary (returned by method 1) and pass it as parameter to method 2.

```
viewerIDs = Parent.GetViewerList()
if (len(viewerIDs) <= 0):
    return
viewerIDsNames = Parent.GetDisplayNames(viewerIDs)
viewerNames = []
for key in viewerIDsNames:
    viewerNames.append(str(viewerIDsNames[key]))
#Get their ranks
viewerRanks  = Parent.GetRanksAll (viewerNames)
```

I get the below error in the last line

> Expected List[str], got list

I have tried the below methods, to set viewerNames and i am facing the same error

```
#viewerNames = viewerIDsNames.items()
#viewerNames = list(viewerIDsNames.values())
#viewerNames = map(str,viewerIDsNames.values())
#viewerNames = [str(name) for name in viewerIDsNames]
```

Can anyone please point out how I can cast this properly.

Regards,
Joshua.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you run this code, or when you try to lint it?  If the latter, you need to tell the linter that viewerNames is `List[str]`.   `viewerNames = [] # type: List[str]`

Comment: Thank you Frank. I believe this worked. Edit: How do i mark this as answered.

Comment: I'll add my comment as an actual answer, and you can "check" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're getting this answer from a linter rather than from Python itself.  You need to tell the linter that `viewerNames` is `List[str]`

```
viewerNames = []  # type: List[str]
```

Some linters try to figure out the type of a variable from the very first time it is assigned, and never look any further.  When you assign `[]` to `viewerName`, the linter knows that it is a list, but has no idea what's inside the list.